# Scale data points on a graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to take data points that I already have in a file and scale them, so they are percentages out of 100.  Right now, the data is scaled from integers 0-4, where 0 signifies 0, 1 signifies 25, 2 signifies 50, 3 signifies 75, and 4 signifies 100.  The data that I want to scale is in one column called `'percent_of_Surface_Area_Covered_by_Tunicates'`.  To be more clear, how do I get the data from this column to scale to its counterpart.

Here is my data...

```
"Date""Latitude and Longitude","Shoots with Tunicates","Shoots without Tunicates","Reproductive Shoots without Tunicates","Reproductive Shoots with Tunicates","Length of Longest Leaf","Number of Leaves per Plant","% of Surface Area Covered by Tunicates(0-4)"
"mm/dd/yyyy","deg sec N deg sec W","YorN","YorN", "YorN","YorN","cm","", "Percent"
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,123,4,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,86,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,0,1,0,0,11,3,1
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,38,4,1
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,47,4,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,101,4,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,85.5,3,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,70,3,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,25,2,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,90,5,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,88,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,81,4,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,67,4,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,73,2,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,81,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,72,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,65,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,20,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,68,2,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,25,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,33,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,86,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,83,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,39,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,55,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,108,2,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,71,1,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,148,1,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,77,4,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,100,4,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,102,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,97.5,4,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,149,3,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,82,3,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,45,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,142,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,89,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,132,4,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,86,4,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,116,2,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,28,1,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,47,3,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,88,3,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,49,3,2
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,103,3,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,106,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,62.5,1,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,87,3,3
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,119,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,118,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,134,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,124.5,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,125,4,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,86,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,65,1,4
"7/29/2013",42º 15.041’ N 070º 46.621’ W,1,0,0,0,59,1,3
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,84.5,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,91.8,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,92.1,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,70.9,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,42.6,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,65.3,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,76.4,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,22.9,6,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,59,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,52,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,77.2,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,86.5,6,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,91.2,6,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,78,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,79.3,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,73,6,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,50.2,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,63,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,75.1,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,64.5,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,83.5,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,87,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,75.9,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,87.5,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,81.9,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,50,3,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,88.5,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,60.2,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,58.5,5,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,43.8,4,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,52.7,3,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,24.1,3,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,52.1,3,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,46.5,3,1
"8/14/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,10.3,2,2

"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,114.6,4,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,85.4,5,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,95,6,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,111.6,5,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,114.8,4,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,71.6,1,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,97.1,5,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,45.5,4,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,95.5,5,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,86.6,6,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,96,5,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,1,0,0,0,60,5,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.088’ N 070º 46.570’ W,0,1,0,0,84.4,5,1

"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,1,0,0,0,97.5,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,102.7,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,1,0,0,0,122.6,4,2
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,9.2,2,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,108.9,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,81.3,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,107.8,2,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,58.7,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,71.3,3,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,75.8,1,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,79.6,1,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,96.1,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,127.3,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,114.8,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,115.1,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,95.2,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,118.5,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,106.6,6,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,107.9,5,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,76.6,5,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,66.3,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,80.9,3,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,1,0,0,0,93.1,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,1,0,0,0,102.6,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,1,0,0,0,94.4,5,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,1,0,0,0,95.5,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,14.8,2,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,56.2,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,101,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,78.1,4,1
"8/26/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,85.2,2,1
"8/19/2013",42º 15.069’ N 070º 46.598’ W,0,1,0,0,61.1,3,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,56,4,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,39,4,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,38,4,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,0,1,0,0,64,1,0
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,0,1,0,0,46,4,0
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,76,5,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,52,4,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,59,5,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,58,1,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,52,5,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,71,4,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,62,4,2
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,0,1,0,0,50,4,0
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,82,4,2
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,110,5,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,96,5,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,88,4,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,64,4,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,94,5,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,82,5,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,78,5,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,0,1,0,0,59,5,0
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,68,4,1
"7/17/2014",42º 14.868' N 70º 46.859' W,1,0,0,0,87,5,1
```

Here is the code that I am currently using to make the graphs...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NAMESLong=["Date","Latitude and Longitude","Shoots with Tunicates","Shoots without       Tunicates","Reproductive Shoots without Tunicates","Reproductive Shoots with Tunicates","Length of Longest Leaf","Number of Leaves per Plant","% of Surface Area Covered by Tunicates(0-4)","Sample Number"]
NAMES= ["Date","LatLon","Shoots_with_Tunicates","Shoots_without_Tunicates","Reproductive_Shoots_without_Tunicates","Reproductive_Shoots_with_Tunicates","Length_of_Longest_Leaf","Number_of_Leaves_per_Plant","percent_of_Surface_Area_Covered_by_Tunicates","sample_number"]

plt.figure(8)
plt.plot(D['percent_of_Surface_Area_Covered_by_Tunicates'],'r.-')
plt.title('Percent of Surface Area Covered by Tunicates')
plt.xlabel('Sample Number')
plt.ylabel('% Scaled to 0-4')
plt.legend([''],loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

Sorry about all the extra data.  All I need help with right now is the scaling of the `'percent_of_Surface_Area_Covered_by_Tunicates'` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so simple, it's almost not worth an answer...
basic math tells us to just multiply your value with 25, than you get values of 0,25,50,75 and 100.

In code, just change your plot-command accordingly:

```
plt.plot(D['percent_of_Surface_Area_Covered_by_Tunicates']*25,'r.-')
```

Hope that helps...